# Some special sets of another one

Tags: calculus, general-topology

I am asked to say which is the derived set ($A'$) (it contains all derived points), the boundary ($Fr A$), the closure ($\overline(A)$) and the interior ($\dot{A}$) over $\mathbb{R} $of the following sets:

a) $A = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty [-1,\frac{1}{n})$

b) $B = (0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}$

c) $C = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n})$

My reasoning was the following:

In the case of $A$, the interior is $(-1,0)$ since all those intersections tend to 0 and the only points which are surely contained by a "ball" (which would be an interval) of certain radius are those I mentioned. However, the closure is [-1,0] since each element of the set is in the closure but there is no element bigger than 0 there because you can choose any huge $N$ and pick a bigger one and the number is still smaller. -1 and 0 are in the closure because the intersection between any interval centered in those points and the set is always different from the empty set. This reason is why the derived set is the same as the closure since there is no problem if we take out -1 and 0. The boundary is the set {-1,0} since these points are the only one which intersect with the set and the complementary.

In the case of B, the interior is null. There is no possible interval in which rationals are contained without meeting irrationals. The derived set is also empty since if we take out each rational, there is no intersection between the set and an interval centered in those rationals without them. However, closure is the closed interval $[0,1]$ since if we do not remove those numbers, the intersection between an interval centered in rationals and irrationals is never empty because of the density. The boundary is the set itself and the numbers 0 and 1.

To end with this, let's examine C. It is composed by an infinite union of open intervals, therefore the interior is itself. The derived set and the closure are the same because of the fact that we are discussing about intervals and there is no problem if we remove each point of the set: the intersection is never null: $[0,1]$ and the boundary is the set of numbers $\frac{1}{n}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. It is an open set since it is the union of open sets (correct me if I am wrong: I'm not sure if this is true when talking about infinite unions, even though it is numerable).
This is what I thought, I only want someone to correct my reasoning. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most of your answers look correct, but I do see a few mistakes.

---

Note that

$$A = \bigcap_{n = 1}^\infty \left[ -1, \frac{1}{n} \right) = [-1, 0]$$

From this, it is easily seen that ${\rm Int} A = (-1, 0)$, and since $A$ is closed, ${\rm Cl} A = A = [-1, 0]$. The boundary is ${\rm Bd} A = {\rm Cl} A - {\rm Int} A = \{-1, 0\}$. Each point in $A$ is easily checked to be a limit point of $A$, and since $A$ is closed, there can be no limit points outside of $A$; therefore, we have $A' = A = [-1, 0]$.

---

For $B = (0, 1) \cap \mathbb{Q}$, we indeed have ${\rm Int} B = \emptyset$. You can also show that every point $x \in [0, 1]$ is a limit point of $B$, and that $B$ has no limit points outside of $[0, 1]$ (shown below). Therefore, ${\rm Cl} B = B' = [0, 1]$. The boundary is ${\rm Bd} B = {\rm Cl} B - {\rm Int} B = {\rm Cl} B = [0, 1]$.

---

Being a union of open intervals, $C$ is itself open and thus ${\rm Int} C = C$. Just as in the previous part, it is possible to show that every point $x \in [0, 1]$ is a limit point of $C$, and that $C$ has no limit points outside of $[0, 1]$. Therefore, ${\rm Cl} C = C' = [0, 1]$. The boundary is ${\rm Cl} C - {\rm Int} C = [0, 1] - C = \left\{ \frac{1}{n} \big| n \in \mathbb{Z}^+ \right\} \cup \{0\}$.

---

So, looking at your answers:

- In (B), the set of limit points is *not* empty. Take any $x \in (0, 1)$ and any basis element $(x - \varepsilon, x + \varepsilon)$ of $\mathbb{R}$ containing $x$ (with $\varepsilon > 0$). By the density of the rationals, we have that there must exist some $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ satisfying $q \in (\max \{0, x - \varepsilon\}, x)$; for such $q$, clearly $q \in B$, and clearly, $q < x \implies q \ne x$. Showing that $0$ and $1$ are also limit points of $B$ is also straightforward: given a neighborhood $(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$ containing $0$, density of the reals guarantees $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $q \in (0, \min \{\varepsilon, 1\})$ showing that $q \in B$; in the same way, given a neighborhood $(1 - \varepsilon, 1 + \varepsilon)$ containing $1$, there is $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $q \in (\max \{0, 1 - \varepsilon\}, 1)$ showing that $q \in B$.
- In (B), the boundary is not just "the set itself and the numbers $0$ and $1$". All of the irrational numbers in $[0, 1]$ are part of the boundary as well.
- In (C), the boundary is not just "the set of numbers $\frac{1}{n}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$". The point $0$ is not contained in the interior of $C$ but it is a limit point of $C$ and is therefore part of the boundary of $C$ as well.

Comment: Thanks for your dedication to this answer. Therefore, in B, the boundary would be the interval [0,1]?

Comment: Yes, ${\rm Bd} B$ is the *entire* interval $[0, 1]$. This is because the interior is empty, so $B \subseteq {\rm Bd} B$.